# Django edit form won't validate on form.save() with user field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, manytomanyfield

I recently added a "user" field to my Game model. I can create a new game that works fine; it's when I want to allow a user to edit the instance of a game where I am running into problems. My view is calling the `form = GameForm(request.POST, instance=game)` where `game = Game.objects.get(pk=id)`. The form is pre-populated with the correct data, but when it's submitted, whether there are updates or not, the form is not validating. It sees it as a POST, but cannot get inside the `if form.is_valid()` conditional. And this is ever since I added the user field. I am using the default Django User model, and the field name is called "owner." It is set up as a `ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)` as users can own many games, and games can be owned by many users. Django forms the Many-To-Many "through" table, but I don't want the user to be able to change who owns what. I have it as a hidden field in my `forms.py` so a user can't change it.

**Model**

```py
class Game(models.Model):
    game_title = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                  verbose_name='Game Title',
                                  db_column='game',
                                  blank=False,
                                  null=False,
                                  unique=True)
    game_developer = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                      verbose_name='Developer',
                                      db_column='developer',
                                      blank=True,
                                      null=True)
    game_release = models.DateField(max_length=50,
                                    verbose_name='Release Date',
                                    db_column='release_date',
                                    blank=False,
                                    null=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Game Rating',
                                 db_column='rating',
                                 choices=INT_CHOICES,
                                 blank=True,
                                 null=True)
    game_genre = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                  verbose_name='Genre',
                                  db_column='genre',
                                  blank=False,
                                  null=True,
                                  choices=GENRE_CHOICES)
    game_platform = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                     verbose_name='Game Platform',
                                     db_column='platform',
                                     blank=True,
                                     choices=PLATFORM_CHOICES)
    game_esrb = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                 verbose_name='ESRB Rating',
                                 db_column='esrb',
                                 blank=False,
                                 null=True)
    owner = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.game_title

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tbl_games'
        verbose_name = 'Game'
```

**View**

```py
# Allows the user to update game information
def editGame(request, id):
    # Finds the user selected game by game id
    game = Game.objects.get(pk=id)
    user = request.user.id

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Seen as POST")
        # Create game instance pre-populated into a form
        form = GameForm(request.POST, instance=game)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form is valid!")
            # Saves the edits without saving to the dB
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Game successfully updated!')
            return redirect('library')
    else:
        print('Seen as GET')
        form = GameForm(instance=game)
    print("Page loaded")
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'library/editGame.html', context)
```

**Form**

```py
class GameForm(ModelForm):

    game_esrb = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=HiddenInput)
    owner = forms.HiddenInput()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = [
            'game_title', 'game_developer', 'rating', 'game_release',
            'game_genre', 'game_platform', 'game_esrb', 'owner'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'rating': Select(attrs={'choices': INT_CHOICES}),
            'game_genre': Select(attrs={'choices': GENRE_CHOICES}),
            'game_platform': Select(attrs={'choices': PLATFORM_CHOICES}),
            'esrb_rating': HiddenInput(),
            'owner': HiddenInput
        }
        help_texts = {
            'rating':
                'Key: 1 - Bad | 2 - Okay | 3 - Average | 4 - Good | 5 - Great'
        }
```

Template

```py
{% block appcontent %}
<div class="height">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <div class="form-btn">
      <a class=" btn btn-secondary cancel" type="button" href="{% url 'library' %}">Cancel</a>
      <button class="update btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove 'owner' from the list assigned to fields in your GameForm class:

```
class Meta:
    model = Game
    fields = [
        'game_title', 'game_developer', 'rating', 'game_release',
        'game_genre', 'game_platform', 'game_esrb',      # 'owner' removed
    ]
```

Here's why: inside your ModelForm, you only need to name the Game fields **that you want to use as input fields** in the form. In your case, you don't actually want the 'owner' field to be an input field, so just leave it out of this list. This will accomplish your stated goal of disallowing a user from modifying the owner field.

Now let's look at, and modify, your view:

1. You do this in your view: "user = request.user.id" This will assign an int to your attribute 'user'. I'm guessing you wanted a user object, not an int, but it's not clear, since you never actually use this attribute anywhere in your view.
2. Here's what needs to happen: Your view needs to connect the user object to the game object, then save the game object. We've already made sure that 'owner' doesn't appear as an input field in your form. Now, we need to manually provide a value for that field, then save the object. Below, we do this following the is_valid() call in your view:

   ```
    def editGame(request, id):
        # Finds the user selected game by game id
        game = Game.objects.get(pk=id)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("Seen as POST")
            # Create game instance pre-populated into a form
            form = GameForm(request.POST, instance=game)

            if form.is_valid():
                print("Form is valid!")
                form.save()

                game.owner.add(request.user)   # update the game's owner field, assigning the current user
                game.save()

                messages.success(request, 'Game successfully updated!')
                return redirect('library')
   ```

To summarize and clarify: The end result of all this work is an updated Game object. The user updates values via the ModelForm. The view validates those changes, then saves the form, which saves the corresponding game object. Then, we manually assign the user to the 'owner' field of the game, because we intentionally left that field out of the form. Then we save the game again so this change is included in the 'final' state of the object.